# Tiling + Texture Atlas on a Per-Face Basis

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have recently been working on a voxel game that uses greedy meshes. Faces will vary from 1*1 to 64*64 unity. For the flat areas in the game it makes more sense to combine multiple smaller terrain tiles into bigger ones with a tiled texture, but this poses a problem for my sprite atlas. Each uv has a reference to a spot on the atlas, but for larger *greedy* faces the texture gets stretched. I want the uv to tile the correct amount of times on a per-face basis to produce the same result as if the larger faces were a bunch of smaller ones, only without the extra geometry.

Here is an example of what I want that was achieved in openGl:

[OpenGl Face-Based-Tiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMCPw.jpg)

See how the larger faces are tiled to give the impression of smaller ones? The texture was from an atlas similar to the following:

[Texture Atlas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guYyG.png)

I only have a basic knowledge of shaders in unity, but how would I write a shader in unity to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you need to first pass the shader a few bits of information: The x and y dimensions of the face (in terms of tiles) and the uv coordinates of the lower left and upper right corners of the tile. You can then use the following equations to calculate the uv coordinates assuming the face's uv values (inputUV) range from the lower left corner to the upper right corner of the sprite:

```
float2 newUV = (inputUV - llCorner)/(urCorner - llCorner); //converts from input uv to values between (0.0, 0.0) and (1.0, 1.0)
newUV.x = newUV.x * xDim % 1; //makes the newUV coordinates repeat xDim times on the x axis
newUV.y = newUV.y * yDim % 1; //makes the newUV coordinates repeat yDim times on the y axis
newUV = newUV*(urCorner - llCorner) + llCorner; //converts values between (0.0, 0.0) and (1.0, 1.0) to values between the lower left corner and the upper right corner
```

I haven't actually tested it, but I think this should work. I hope this helps!